# What are sha3Uncles and why are they mostly same for all blocks

Tags: sha3, uncle-blocks

I was looking at sha3Uncles in my chain and found it to be constant throughout. After looking at the example response to JSON RPC requests, I found the same value:

```
0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347
```

Moreover, when I traversed etherscan, I found this value to remain more or less constant throughout blocks.

**Question:**

What are sha3uncles? And why do they mostly have a constant value?

An existing similar question [what is Sha3Uncles?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39536/what-is-sha3uncles) does not explain clearly as to how this particular hash was calculated, or where it came from?